# How can I store an element attribute for later use before setting it to an empty string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery code:

```
  $(targetSelector)
    .attr('data-disabled', 'yes')
    .attr('title', '')
    .addClass('disabled')
    .prop('disabled', true);
```

How can I change this code so that before the title attribute is set to '' I take the current value of the title and store it in the 'data-title' attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(targetSelector).attr({
    'data-disabled': 'yes',
    'data-title': function() { return this.title }
    'title': ''
  }).addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);
```

The other answers are similar, however accessing `this.title` will only work if `this` is the element, and that depends on the context. The method above uses the function attribute to return the title instead.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest:

```
$(targetSelector).attr({
    'data-disabled': 'yes',
    'data-title': function() {
        return this.title;
    }
}).attr('title', '').addClass('disabled').prop('disabled', true);​
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/sh92r/1/).

References:

- [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).
- [`data()`](http://api.jquery.com//).

Comment: How do you know that `this` is the target?

Comment: Thanks very much. I also learned something else new. I did not know that I could set multiple attributes at once. Hope this question helps others. Should it be this or $(this) ?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$(targetSelector)
.attr({'data-disabled' : 'yes', 'data-title' : function() {return this.title;}})  // set the title before it is removed
.attr('title', '')
.addClass('disabled')
.prop('disabled', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(targetSelector)
    .attr('data-disabled' : 'yes')
    .attr('data-title', $(this).attr('title'))
    .attr('title', '')
    .addClass('disabled')
    .prop('disabled', true);
```