# How can I set the title on an element from an attribute of the element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the following code:

```
    $(targetSelector)
        .attr({
            'data-disabled': 'yes',
            'data-title': function() { return this.title },
            'title': ''
        })
        .addClass('disabled')
        .prop('disabled', true);
```

This sets the element's title to '' after first having stored it in data-title.

How can I restore the elements title by getting it back from the data-title attribute if the title is currently equal to the empty string? I assume I need to do this in a function like the above but how can I code in a check into the function?

Comment: This is maybe related to your previous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13584148/how-can-i-store-an-element-attribute-for-later-use-before-setting-it-to-an-empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$(targetSelector).attr('title', function() {
    return this.title || $(this).data('title');
});
```

If will return the title if it is *falsy*, else it will grab the data-title attribute.

Comment: your last answer that I accepted used this.title and this answer uses $(this).data   Can you explain why this is. I am bit confused. Thanks.

Comment: `this.title` is the title attribute. `$(this).data('title')` is the `data-title` attribute, so it will return the title if it exists, otherwise it will grab the data-title.

Comment: @Anne this.title looks for an attribute on the DOM element whereas $(this).data uses a method on a jQuery selection.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you atore in a `data-*` attribute is accessible from jQuerys `data(name)` method where name is what follows `data-` so you can use the below code

```
$(targetSelector)
    .attr('title',function() { return this.title || $(this).data("title"); })
```

This will also set the title if the attribute `title` is not present or if this.title returns any other falsy value (e.g. `false`) however I'm assuming that you wish to set the value in both the cases where this.title === "" and this.title === undefined and that the latter is not expected (which would require that the title attribute at some point was set explicitly to the boolean value `false`

Comment: But I only want this to happen if the title is currently == ''

Comment: @David yes it does not so surprisingly since it looks very similar to my original answer with the exception that I did not see the requirement for only setting it when empty and the explanation that you as well as I are violating the requirement as stated since values such as `false` and undefined will result in the attribute being set which conflicts with the requirement "only when this.title  is the empty string :)